# instanceof not working for a JSON object - why?

Tags: android, instanceof

[image: check this link for the response]Hi in the below code key name as value was acting as a object and string .want to check with the name .if name is matches with that then it should check two condition value is object or string .

if value is object then if condition should execute otherwise else condition should execute .but it is not going any of the loop.

can any one tell me where i did the mistake

Json Response:

```
{
  "name": "account_id",
  "value": {
      "value": "11x52927",
      "label": "Alfa HOSPITAL"
  },
  "label": "Account Name",
  "uitype": "51",
  "type": {
      "defaultValue": null
  }
},
{
  "name": "cf_905",
  "value": "Intensive Care Medicine",
  "label": "Specialization",
  "uitype": "16",
  "type": {
      "defaultValue": null
  }
},
```

Contacts.java:

```
for (SynFields synFields1: synFields) {

    String name = synFields1.getName();

    if (name.equals("account_id")) {
        Object values = synFields1.getValue();

        try {

            if (values == JSONObject.NULL) {
                // Handle NULL
            } else if (values instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject1 = new
                    JSONObject(String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue()));
                    String value = ((JSONObject) values).getString("value");
                    String labels = ((JSONObject) values).getString("label");

                    account_names.add(labels);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                String value_accounts = String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue());
                account_names.add(value_accounts);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SynField.java:

```
public class SynFields {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @SerializedName("label")
    @Expose
    private String label;

}
```

Comment: {
                                        "value": "11x52927",
                                        "label": "Alfa HOSPITAL"
                                    }

Comment: would you please share your `SynFields` model class.

Comment: @JakirHossain synFields class have shared and with the above response was like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `Object` to `JSONObject` using `Gson`.

Try like this

```
try {
     if (values == Null) {
         // Handle null object
         continue;
     }
     if(values instanceof String){
         String value_accounts = String.valueOf(values);
         account_names.add(value_accounts);
     }else{
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(values)); // convert Object to JSONObject
         String value = jsonObject.getString("value");
         String labels = jsonObject.getString("label");

         account_names.add(labels);
     }

 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```